# MySql query group by day and stop 18

Tags: mysql, group

MySql query stop group 18 day and forward.

AEG - datetime

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  AEG,
     max(KWHI2) - min(KWHI2) AS PV
FROM LOGPV WHERE 1    
GROUP BY DAY( AEG )    
ORDER BY AEG DESC LIMIT 5`
```

and this answer

```
AEG                     PV 
2023-04-18 00:00:07     43.854
2023-04-17 00:00:38     55.725
2023-04-16 00:00:53     43.495
2023-04-15 00:00:16     45.724
2023-04-14 00:00:44     59.384
```

But it should be `18-22.04.2023`

Is there any error in my SQL statement?

Comment: day will give back 1-31 and group by that, so your data don't have enough dates to get all month. you should check the date functions again https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is currently grouping by day only. To fix this issue, you should group by year, month, and day:

```
SELECT
    DATE(AEG) AS AEG_Date,
    MAX(KWHI2) - MIN(KWHI2) AS PV
FROM
    LOGPV
WHERE
    AEG >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
GROUP BY
    YEAR(AEG),
    MONTH(AEG),
    DAY(AEG)
ORDER BY
    AEG_Date DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Many thanks!

` AEG_Date   PV  
2023-04-22  59.457
2023-04-21  56.543
2023-04-20  61.128
2023-04-19  65.168
2023-04-18  43.854`

Comment: Great! could you please like the answer or mark as correct if you think so